# Get a number in an unordered straight that follow a start value from an interval

Tags: arrays

I search a fast method to perform my problem.

imagine ordered seats numeroted from 1 to 8, imagine they are people on seats [ 2, 6, 5, 3 ]. i want to get back the second (interval +2) people after the seat number 4 (start value)

for examples :

with this array : **[2, 5, 8, 7, 1]** , i started with value **3** and i move **+2** times,
the third next number in the list is 5, the second is **7**, the method must return this value

with the same **[2, 5, 8, 7, 1]** , i started from **7** and i move **+3** times
here the method must return to the minimal value. trought 8.. 1.. 2.., result : **2**

with **[1, 3]**, start **4**, count **+2**, result **3**

with **[5, 3, 9]**, start **3**, count **+1**, result **5**

with **[5, 3, 9]**, start **3**, count **+2**, result **9**

I hope someone will understand my problem.
thanks you

Comment: Please try to give a more detailed description of an example input, the steps to be performed and an example output.

Comment: I really could not follow your examples. When you say [1, 3] start 4, what do you mean by start 4?

Answer (score 4):

Sort your list, use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) to find the starting index, then mod the result of the addition by the length of the list.

Comment: I am glad you understood this question. :-D

Comment: imagine ordered seats numeroted from 1 to 8, imagine they are people on seats [ 2, 6, 5, 3 ]. i want to get back the second (+2) people after the seat number 4 (start value)

Comment: @Dalou: How doesn't my algorithm do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is basically just an example implementation of Ignacio's algorithm in Python:

```
from bisect import bisect

def circular_highest(lst, start, move):
    slst = sorted(lst)
    return slst[(bisect(slst, start) - 1 + move) % len(lst)]

print circular_highest([2, 5, 8, 7, 1], 3, 2)
print circular_highest([2, 5, 8, 7, 1], 7, 3)
print circular_highest([1, 3], 4, 2)
print circular_highest([5, 3, 9], 3, 1)
print circular_highest([5, 3, 9], 3, 2)
```

Output:

```
7
2
3
5
9
```